# How to align text in a WPF menu item?

Tags: c#, wpf, text, alignment

How to align text in a menu item? I tried with vertical content alignment, but didn't work. It worked only for `Button` and `TextBox`.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="652" Width="1054">
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="617" Width="1041">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApplication4;component/Images/hp-colorful-books-hd-105609.jpg" />
    </Grid.Background>
    <ToolBarPanel Height="42" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,91,0,0" Name="toolBarPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1043" Background="#FFEEEEEE" />
    <Grid Height="472" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,133,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="213" Background="#FFF0F0F0">
        <MenuItem Height="40" Name="menuItem1" Width="209" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Header="Folder" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Normal" FontStretch="Expanded" FontFamily="Verdana" FontStyle="Normal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Padding="1" Margin="1,0,3,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" >
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="/WpfApplication4;component/Images/Computer.png" />
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Show what have you tried.

Comment: Code, show your code.

Comment: This is rude , down voters must atleast specify the reason why they did it . After all he is just a newbie all of us were once in his place just remember that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
<MenuItem.Header>
    <TextBlock Text="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</MenuItem.Header>
```

Comment: if only there was a way to templatize this

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't work at all for me. I tried using the menu item control template and style as well, but that didn't work either.