# C# statement Programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I cannot figure out why the following C# statement:

```
Des.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

Is accepted by the compiler but doesn't give the desired result.
Any clarification much appreciated.

XAML is almost empty, only the “Grid Name” is defined.
The code is executed at initialization to generate a ‘Menu Strip’. Other ‘MenuItem Properties’ are handled correctly programmatically, for example:

```
InitializeComponent();

// Generate a Menu Strip
Menu MS = new Menu();
Gname.Children.Add(MS);
MS.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
MS.Width = 300;
MS.Height = 80;
MS.Background = Brushes.Yellow;

// Add stuff to menu
MenuItem Des = new MenuItem();
Des.Header = "Description";
Des.FontSize = 20;
Des.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center; // available in IntelliSense 
MS.Items.Add(Des);
```

Position at the centre within the menu strip (IntelliSense does not offer Bottom and Top but dutifully show Center)

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569091/how-to-align-text-in-a-wpf-menu-item) You need to set the `Header` and then set the alignment of whatever you put in the `Header` (like a `TextBlock`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The idea here is to avoid any XAML primitive and produce equivalent results via the c# language only. Unfortunately, it seems that not all of the properties/characteristics can be set programmatically. However the compiler should react to improbable statements.

Comment: *The idea here is to avoid any XAML primitive and produce equivalent results via the c# language only.* - that's kind of the point, and the power of WPF. *Unfortunately, it seems that not all of the properties/characteristics can be set programmatically.* of course they can. The difference is that XAML does a lot of implicit conversions for you which makes doing in programmatically a bit more verbose.

Comment: Thanks again for your time. While I'm not arguing for or against the merits of XAML, I think I haven’t been clear enough – is it possible to use c# on its own or it contains too much vanilla? How does stack-up against, say, c, c++ and java…cont.

Comment: …Your confidence in the c# language suggest that you know something that I don’t; therefore please suggest how can I make the MenuItem “Description”, using only c# regular expression, move up or down within the Menustrip (Center and bottom would suffice) and if not possible why the compiler treated as syntactically legal the expression: Des.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;